# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key - why can I not use pd.cut() on a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I can see other questions like this, but I can't make their solutions apply to me.

I wrote this code:

```
print(list(output_dataframe2['confidence_range'][0:100]))

output_dataframe2['confidence_range'] = output_dataframe2.apply(lambda x:  pd.cut(output_dataframe2['confidence_range'][0:100], [.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]),axis=0)
```

The output is:

```
[0.07104106198775281, 0.07681671628936017, 0.07361285547872579, 0.08426241375111888, 0.09426695249304227, 0.07277908132090657, 0.07596724274867177, 0.07787474884487028, 0.08358131238791791, 0.08979761469763338, 0.0738640345607251, 0.07940320140205635, 0.07209276394982556, 0.08757624799906928, 0.08706375208832365, 0.08468075287090132, 0.07730884031039793, 0.07856973785669046, 0.07274862945070759, 0.0866920395113026, 0.08264507927872311, 0.07700725993664485, 0.07368871066870882, 0.07401282247556824, 0.09264612764035488, 0.07506796627630956, 0.0768855363708753, 0.07964452700851928, 0.08487824723635753, 0.08352372310793824, 0.06922871463061396, 0.07166240445643876, 0.08819215856746335, 0.05966794067700878, 0.11124878166847511, 0.0729335885241208, 0.07665325146784958, 0.07396848782906056, 0.08027918516027988, 0.09616548701868913, 0.08648937017004929, 0.07801954928982695, 0.07423476277949745, 0.06942205668967497, 0.09183426107095122, 0.08119386568499445, 0.07444504948553582, 0.07575145788881914, 0.07118742056835665, 0.0974222063722939, 0.09315645088182262, 0.08005020335656701, 0.07474181396368278, 0.0730391962226974, 0.0790123355752301, 0.08790051937652928, 0.0704054007555723, 0.0801805303973437, 0.06953606070228636, 0.09197748876826825, 0.09076666961309225, 0.08183623321317493, 0.07216188648568382, 0.071346024927791, 0.08388918576025792, 0.07270914338733125, 0.0760779087199434, 0.07572877736238637, 0.08134053178046392, 0.09414363874987498, 0.0771266479863377, 0.07900226799968604, 0.0734475982159013, 0.07818121341259629, 0.09224227238547858, 0.07620283778757117, 0.07974822882133276, 0.07710022848031366, 0.07872257722347716, 0.0882261276873052, 0.08622834993827369, 0.07922132900022591, 0.07721666773385354, 0.07352610284819554, 0.08380755047945128, 0.09196214043970832, 0.07826503361885426, 0.07584399258623933, 0.07284303664930264, 0.08108579670589533, 0.08047644130850443, 0.07668602971100233, 0.07450088794646745, 0.07493849851839753, 0.0933981425156282, 0.07821852119931488, 0.08129869040488961, 0.07660410131185957, 0.07842259381874718, 0.08545609326518866]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dataframe.py", line 18, in <module>
    output_dataframe2['confidence_range'] = output_dataframe2.apply(lambda x:  pd.cut(output_dataframe2['confidence_range'][0:100], [.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]),axis=0)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3602, in __setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3729, in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Could someone explain to me why those list of numbers cannot be cut with the lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the lambda function you have would work.  I messed around with it and it appears that it can work but I'm not sure why it would work.

You are doing an entire vectorized operation on each row of the DF via `apply()` using the lambda function.  Not sure then how the underlying assignment works in that case.  You are returning a full column slice for each row.  It looks like the engine can pick out the right value using the index.  But sometimes I got the same error that you did.

It would be cleaner to just do the vectorized operation on its own:

```
output_dataframe2['confidence_range'] = pd.cut(output_dataframe2['confidence_range'][0:100], [.3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1])
```

Also, your lowest bin of 0.3 is greater than any value in your supplied list.  So the returned bins will all be `NaN`s.